# NullPointerException using @autowired in Vaadin and Spring

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, vaadin, autowired

I am working on simple bookLibrary project in Vaadin 8 and Spring. I am struggling with injecting service class into UI components. It gives me nullPointerExceptionMessage all the time. I do not use "new" to create service anywhere.

Here is LibraryService class:

```
 @Service
    public class LibraryService {
    @Autowired
    private BookDao bookDao;
    @Autowired
    private LibraryDao libraryDao;

    private static LibraryService libraryServiceInstance;

    private LibraryService() {

    }

    public static LibraryService getInstance() {
        if (libraryServiceInstance == null) {
            synchronized (LibraryService.class) {
                if (libraryServiceInstance == null) {
                    libraryServiceInstance = new LibraryService();
                }
            }
        }
        return libraryServiceInstance;
    }

    public void saveBook(Book book) {
        libraryDao.findAll().forEach(l -> l.getBooks().add(book));
        book.setLibrary(libraryDao.findOne(1L));
        bookDao.save(book);
    }

    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
        libraryDao.findAll().forEach(l -> l.getBooks().forEach(b -> bookList.add(b)));
        return bookList;
    }

}
```

GridLayout looks like this:

```
 @UIScope
    @Component
    public class GridLayout extends CustomComponent {

    @Autowired
    LibraryService libraryService; //this is null

    Grid<Book> bookGrid = new Grid<>(Book.class);
    VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();


    public GridLayout(){
        createMainLayout();
        createGrid();
    }

    private void createMainLayout() {
        setCompositionRoot(verticalLayout);
    }

    private void createGrid() {
        bookGrid = new Grid<>(Book.class);
        verticalLayout.addComponent(bookGrid);
        List<Book> books = libraryService.getAllBooks();
        bookGrid.setItems(books);
        bookGrid.removeAllColumns();
        bookGrid.addColumn(Book::getTitle).setCaption("TITLE");
        bookGrid.addColumn(Book::getAuthor).setCaption("AUTHOR");
        bookGrid.addColumn(Book::getYear).setCaption("YEAR");

        verticalLayout.addComponent(bookGrid);
    }
}
```

and main UI code is here :

```
 @SpringUI
    public class LibraryUI extends UI {
    @Autowired
    private LibraryService libraryService;

    @Autowired
    private BookForm bookForm;

    @Autowired
    private GridLayout gridLayout;

    private HorizontalLayout mainLayout;
    private VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        setMainLayout();
        setHeader();
        loadBooks();
        addBookForm();
    }

    public void setMainLayout() {
        mainLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        setContent(mainLayout);

    }

    public void setHeader() {
        Label header = new Label("Library");
        header.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_H1);
        verticalLayout.addComponent(header);
        mainLayout.addComponent(verticalLayout);
        verticalLayout.setComponentAlignment(header, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
        header.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_H1);
    }

     private void loadBooks(){
        mainLayout.addComponent(gridLayout);
    }

    public void addBookForm() {
        mainLayout.addComponent(bookForm);
        mainLayout.setComponentAlignment(bookForm, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    }
```

I will be very grateful for any help or idea what is wrong.

Comment: Could you please add stack trace

Comment: @urag it looks like this: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.vaadin.simpleexercise.ui.GridLayout]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you calling createGrid() from GridLayout constructor the @Autowire injects the beans after constructor was called so what you need to do is something like this

```
  public GridLayout(){

}

@PostConstruct
public init(){
    createMainLayout();
    createGrid();
}
```

Comment: I agree, the problem is Spring related.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich not Spring related. related to wrong usage of Spring

Comment: @urag thank you very much for your help, explaining and fast answers, your solution works! :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: @Kakadu You can mark this post as the correct answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can inject service class like

```java
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
    import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;

    @UIScope
    @Component
    public class GridLayout extends CustomComponent implements ApplicationContextAware {

     private static ApplicationContext context;
     private LibraryService libraryService;

             @Override
     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
            context = applicationContext;
            libraryService = context.getBean(LibraryService.class);   
           }


                Grid<Book> bookGrid = new Grid<>(Book.class);
                VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();


                public GridLayout(){
                    createMainLayout();
                    createGrid();
                }

                private void createMainLayout() {
                    setCompositionRoot(verticalLayout);
                }

                private void createGrid() {
                    bookGrid = new Grid<>(Book.class);
                    verticalLayout.addComponent(bookGrid);
                    List<Book> books = libraryService.getAllBooks();
                    bookGrid.setItems(books);
                    bookGrid.removeAllColumns();
                    bookGrid.addColumn(Book::getTitle).setCaption("TITLE");
                    bookGrid.addColumn(Book::getAuthor).setCaption("AUTHOR");
                    bookGrid.addColumn(Book::getYear).setCaption("YEAR");

                    verticalLayout.addComponent(bookGrid);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got the same error as earlier:( Thank you for your idea:)